# How can I break my computer's audio?

Tags: sound

For reasons I won't get into, I need to ensure that my computer:

- Cannot play audio
- Can only be made to play audio again by re-installing the operating system (per a commenter's suggestion: re-installing Ubuntu from a live USB)
- Can otherwise function completely normally

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

Comment: This seems somewhat impossible without ruining the entire operating system such that it needs to be reinstalled to work at all, since otherwise the steps can simply be undone without reinstalling the operating system.

Comment: click the `mute` button?

Comment: Well, if it's desktop, and the sound card isn't integrated into motherboard, then you probably could just remove it.  With laptops that's a bit of a challenge, because you can't just remove sound card, although you could remove the speakers and somehow break the headphones port. If you have hdmi output there, it's still possible to play audio via hdmi, so that also would need to be addressed some how

Comment: But what I suggest , basically is hardware related. From OS itself, form software side of things, probably removing drivers is OK, if there's no other person with root-level access - that way only you yourself can reinstall drivers if you need them, but that doesn't fall under "re-installing OS only" category.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since what you're asking is basically impossible without tons of modifications to the OS and kernel.

Comment: @AndroidDev that doesn't make the question off-topic.

Comment: Hi @EMBLEM, to give you an answer, I think we really need to know more. Offered solutions depend on what level of security is needed. Even "reinstalling" is a relative thing. Reinstall what part of the operating system? Like always, everything can be surpassed except breaking / removihg hardware. The question is: what level of security would you find an acceptable solution.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this properly, you need a hardware solution. You can't break Ubuntu this way without either making it trivial to undo, or breaking it too much.

Remove the sound card, put hot glue in the jacks, desolder the built-in speakers. And obviously do the same for USB plugs to stop somebody plugging in a USB sound card/speaker. And remove any Bluetooth hardware for the same reason.

If this sounds unacceptable, you might want to give some of these reasons you "won't get into" so we can see what you're *actually* trying to do. At the moment it just sounds like you're trying to break somebody else's computer.

---

Or you could just blacklist the `snd` module. That'll stop any ALSA drivers loading, which means PulseAudio won't have anything to play to (locally).

```
echo 'blacklist snd' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-snd.conf
```

And reboot. It's fairly trivial to fix though, if you know what you're doing.

Comment: More simple method: Create a service that always activates mute  :-D

Answer (score 2):

Chai T. Rex pointed that it can't be achieved, because any steps described here will always be possible to revert and get sound again. This is true.

Anyway, you could [blacklist the sound kernel modules](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux/104699-how-blacklist-audio-modules.html) (drivers). I used `cat /proc/modules | grep snd` to find out which were my modules. Then I added them to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to blacklist them. Add `blacklist {module_name}` per each module. Then reboot.

As a result, when I try to run MOC, I get:

```
myusr@myhost:~$ mocp
Running the server...
Trying JACK...
Trying ALSA...
Trying OSS...

FATAL_ERROR: No valid sound driver!


FATAL_ERROR: Server exited!
```

Also, to take it a bit further, remove linux-sound-base: `sudo apt-get remove linux-sound-base`.

If you take away the user's ability to install new packages, then he won't be able to reinstall it. Create a new user and remove him from sudoers or just allow him to sudo on certain commands.

Comment: I think blacklisting `snd` should suffice. All the snd_* modules depend on it. Edit: Maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A: on boot look into BIOS, most BIOSes have possibility to disable PCI (onboard) devices. If you disable audio there, it requires deeper knowledge (or another question in askubuntu ;) to enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dead set on exactly what you've specified in your question, then this is essentially impossible.

It would require tons of modifications to the OS and kernel.